# Placing button on top of Google maps in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I think the title says it all however I have a couple of questions regarding Google Maps SDK in iOS app using Swift.

1. I have a tab controller with 2 items however whenever the map is shown the centre to location button is under the tab controller and unable to be clicked. Is there a way to position this or change the actual size of the map so it only uses the available space and not the entire screen.
2. How would I go about placing elements (buttons, text field etc) on top of the map? Every time I add a button it seems to show behind the map.

I am new to Swift development so any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: About second question, You can `self.view insertSubview:(UIView *) aboveSubview:(UIView *)` [Reference to apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/insertSubview:aboveSubview:)

Comment: create a new view and place over your googleMap view and add button to that new view.And if you wanted to perform actions regarding touch on MapView.Use Delegate design Pattern to handle touches and listening to those touches by button.